# How to simulate multiple sizes of clothing on a character?

Tags: simulations, cloth, unreal-5

I'm new to Unreal Engine. I've searched a lot about creating clothes for characters, but haven't succeeded in finding a working solution for this request.

I'm trying to create a virtual try-on application for a brand. We first generate a body based on the user's body parameters. The problem is that we want to simulate multiple clothing sizes on a single body shape.

The closest solution I've found yet is using morphs. but it does not work as I expect.

How can I simulate multiple clothing sizes (ex: xs, s, m, xl, xxl) on a character?

Comment: What did you try using the morphs, and how did the results differ from your expectations? The more detail you can give us about the problem, the better we can help you solve it. You're most likely using just one version of Unreal, so be sure to tag your question with just the version you're using, not multiple.

Comment: @DMGregory I used morphs to change the body shape, but I don't want the cloth size be changed with the body (That it does now). It should be simulated in a way that looks like it has gotten looser or tighter. Also I want to know how to change the cloth size separated than the body. E.g. when we switch the size from S to L, we should see that it got looser and larger.

Comment: Edit your question to include those details. You should also mention how you simulate the clothing at present.